# .NET Entity Framework 4.0 - prevent overwrite

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4.1

I have a ASP.NET 4.0 Web Application Project, it work with edmx model file generate by MSSQL 2008 and named StaffModel.edmx

I have my custom logic and apply to StaffModel.Designer.cs ，today i open the edmx ,but not re-generate form database, just have a look, but VS2010 overwrite my *.Designer.cs in accident!

No message or confirm to ask me overwrite or not, so how can i disable that in VS2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you cannot. .Designer.cs files are autogenerated and should never be modified because every save to EDMX (even after moving some entity in diagram) or T4 template (if you use it) will trigger recreation.

Either move your changes to your own partial classes for your entities or add them directly to code generator - T4 template.